# list of good websites / videos for kids about Hinduism?

Tags: gods

I am planning to build a list of good website or online links about God's stories. My kids everyday ask me to tell story in the night.

Can you suggest good list here ?

Comment: Your question is *Too Broad* for the site. If you want to collect the data for the same, consider asking a question on http://meta.stackexchange.com and flag to a moderator who will later convert your post to community wiki so that all the users can share their inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://kids.baps.org/) website. In there visit section [Things to Know](http://kids.baps.org/thingstoknow/festival/23.htm). It has sub-sections regarding Satsang, Festivals, Scriptures, Hinduism and Sacred Places.

There are [animated stories](http://kids.baps.org/storytime/hindustories.htm) (flash videos) under Story Time:

1. [Satsang](http://kids.baps.org/storytime/satsangstories.htm)
2. [Hindu](http://kids.baps.org/storytime/hindustories.htm)
3. [Moral](http://kids.baps.org/storytime/moralstories.htm)

And there is much more let your kids explore the website.

Answer (score 3):

Sister Nivedita, disciple of Swami Vivekananda, wrote a book called *Cradle Tales of Hinduism*. It was written under Swami Vivekananda's guidance and help (you can see this from Vivekananda's Complete Works, as some of his correspondence with her refers to his reading and corrections of stories to her). It is still available as a book, not sure if it is available softcopy. Google 'Cradle Tales of Hinduism'.

It has Hindu stories of gods and heroes to be read to small children.

Comment: http://www.vivekananda.net/PDFBooks/Nivedita/cradletalesofhinduism%201907.pdf. Link for the book "Cradle Tales of Hinduism".